# Read from file not Printing to Output

Tags: java

Could anyone possibly be able to tell me why this code is not printing out to the output? I am not receiving any errors but it is just not printing. It is reading from a .txt file (which is below the code below).

Code:

```
public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("CarInfo.txt");

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String carTab = sc.next();
                // Looking for tag 'Station:'
                if (!carTab.equals("Car:")) continue;

                if (!sc.hasNext()) {
                    break;
                }

                Car = sc.next();
                if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    continue;
                }
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    continue;
                }
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(car + " " + x + " " + y);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code. That is far easier than having us guess what's wrong.

Comment: I tested your code it's ok

Comment: @Abdelhak does it print out for you?

Comment: Yes @Safa be sure the path is right

Comment: Printed ok for me too.

Comment: @Abdelhak If the path was wrong, the output should read "File not found" I think, unless it happens to find a file with different contents.

Comment: The path can be right or wrong depending on where are you executing your code from. Are you executing it from the same directory where that file is?

Comment: Add a line of code like `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());` and check which file there is in the printed path.

Answer (score 0):

use nextLine() other than next().  nextLine() can consume carriage returns

next()  may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

every time you invoke nextInt(),  it only reads the number, and it will not consume anything after the number